# trigger click automatically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amcharts

I am trying to trigger click automatically after the page load.
Here is the code

```
$("document").ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {

        $(".amcharts-export-menu-top-right").find('a').trigger('click');

    },1000);
});
```

But it is not working

Here is the entire code:
https://jsfiddle.net/32g26a4d/

Comment: You should mention it's for a canvas.  jquery doesn't work so well with canvas.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.

Comment: `.find('a')[0].click()`: https://jsfiddle.net/32g26a4d/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this

```
$("document").ready(function() {

 setTimeout(function() {

    $('.amcharts-main-div .amcharts-export-menu-top-right a')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))

   },1000);
 });
```

JSFiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/en8zxpm5/)

Comment: Or just `[0].click()`

Comment: thank you . It worked. how do I trigger the click even after the chart has been generated,because sometimes it may take more time to generate the chart.

Comment: You can look for some event callback like `rendered`. Check this https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-events/

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `.export-main` class for creating button using **AmCharts** you don't need to use any other class/find method for selecting that `anchor` button. Please follow below code::

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".export-main a")[0].click();
    },1000);
});
```

Working jsfiddle link:: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/32g26a4d/3/)

Comment: That's error prone - if you plan to refer to `[0]` (so extract from jQuery to use JS native methods) you should first check that element exists (Something jQuery kills silently)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I don't think here that error will occur.

Comment: If on some page that element does not exists you'll get a TypeError like `cannot read property click of undefined` - Another reason why we like jQuery, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this during the chart's [`rendered`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#rendered) or [`animationFinished`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#animationFinished) event if you have an animation. `$("document").ready()` doesn't ensure that the chart will be finished loaded as the chart creation process is asynchronous.

Add this to your makeChart call:

```
//if you have startDuration set to a value > 0:
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "animationFinished",
    "method": function() {
      $('.amcharts-main-div .amcharts-export-menu-top-right a')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));       
    }
  }]
});

//if you don't have startDuration set or it is set to 0:
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "rendered",
    "method": function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.amcharts-main-div .amcharts-export-menu-top-right a')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));       
      }, 500)      
    }
  }]
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32g26a4d/4/)